# Div in div with overaly: scroll

Tags: css, sass

Is it somehow possible to ensure that inner div with class .b can be displayed over the outer div (class .a). For non lot of inner div is hidden. Simple z-index doesn't help and I not able to move inner div element outside the outer one.

I have html file :

```
<div class="a">
  <span class="aa">AAAAA
    <div class="b">
      1.A
    </div>
  </span>
  ...
</div>
```

And css style like this :

```
.a {
  position:absolute;
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.b {
  display: none;
  background: #FFF;
  position:absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  width:150px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid blue;
  z-index:10;
}

.aa {
  position: static;
}

.aa:hover .b {
  display: block;
}
```

Here is js fiddle with my specification:

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DuFuS/87m1dc4a/)

Comment: You are required to post your markup and code here, **within your question, not a jsfiddle**. [mcve] A fiddle can compliment your example but not be used in its stead.

Comment: If I understand the question correctly I think you can just set the z-index https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp

Comment: please add your code too.

Comment: Please don't ignore the rules of SO, links to jsfiddle must be accompanied by code in the question.  Marking your link at code annoys us in two ways - you blatantly ignore the rules and you make the link unclickable

Comment: Edited. Sorry for that I was in rush. Z-index doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found solution by myself. Removing position: absolute from div with class a helped.

```
.a {
  width:500px;
  height:50px;
  border:1px solid red;
  overflow-y: auto;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
```